# Eclipse - Runtime classpath external folder wrong path

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime, classpath, eclipse-classpath

I'm trying to add two external folders in my runtime classpath. What I do is to go in `Run -> Run Configurations -> Classpath`, then clicking in `User Entries` and `Advanced -> Add external folder`, then `Apply`.

When I run Eclipse complains saying: *The archive: `<path>` which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.*. But the `<path>` is not the one that I set.

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in eclipse?
If, yes, apply the changes only specific to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple projects in eclipse? If, yes, apply the changes only specific to your project.

```
`project` -> `Build path` ->`Configure Build Path` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Add Class Folder`
```